Login loop in linux
I am stuck in a login loop on my Linux. I tried few solutions available online but they didn't help:
I opened terminal with Ctrl+alt+f3.
It did not show Xauthority file. Then I went to root with cd / and checked the persmissions of the /tmp directory which were  drwxrwxrwt, as expected. Then I followed this video and installed gmd.
And now I have an Xauthority file. For me it shows
-rw------- 1 username username (date) . Xauthority 

What should I do?
Also when entering terminal pwd shows home/username , this has Xauthority
While my tmp folder is in /

Please [edit] your question and i) tell us what Linux you are using, ii) from the terminal, run journalctl -b0 _UID=1000 | curl -F'file=@-' http://0x0.st (this will upload the log from the last boot and return a URL from which we can download it), and post the resulting link here.

The real filename is ".Xauthority". The "."  matters. Also, copy 'n paste your text, rather than retyping a censored version. Often, exact messages are needed for diagnosis.

Thanks everyone, I corrected what was going wrong , I will keep in mind the suggestions in the comments , I am new in the community
